# How do I use NoteIntents?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-implicit-intent, google-voice-actions

I am trying to access NoteIntents.CREATE_NOTE. But neither does Android Studio recognize it nor does it let me import com.google.android.gsm.actions.NoteIntents;

I am trying to create an implicit intent receiver for creating notes. I have been referring to Google Developer Documentation. 
[Link to New Note Intent Section.](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#NewNote)
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your project is not setup with google play services. You can follow [this document](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project) which indicates how to setup the project with google play services.

**Do take a note in the document:**

> Be sure you update this version number each time Google Play services is updated.